# Make LinearLayout in FrameLayout opaque

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-framelayout

I cannot find a way how to make linearLayout opaque. It's always transparent no matter what I do.

[image]

The layout looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/error_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_background_dark"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/error_message"
        android:text="@string/dummy_number"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <!-- The content of this scroll view is seen underneath the errorPanel -->
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <!-- Content of ScrollView -->

  </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

How can I make the LinearLayout opaque? Maybe instead of setting just color I could try to use a solid drawable..?

**Background**

I am using appcompat v7 theme `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`

**Things I tried**

1. Override the theme's panelBackground from transparent to `<item name="android:panelBackground">@android:color/black</item>`
2. Set background as `background=#FF000000` on LinearLayout.
3. Set alpha as `alpha=1` on LinearLayout.
4. Set background as drawable `android:background="@drawable/background_error_panel"` where the drawable is:

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >

       <solid android:color="#FF181818"/>

   </shape>
   ```

**Edit 3/25/2015**

Maybe the animations are the problem..? i use scale anims and in code:

```
public void toggle() {
    panel.setText("Some text  Some text Some text Some text Some text ");
    Animation slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyApplication.context, R.anim.slide_in);
    Animation slideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyApplication.context, R.anim.slide_out);

    if (layout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layout.startAnimation(slideIn);
        layout.setAlpha(1);
    } else {
        layout.startAnimation(slideOut);
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of gray_background_dark?

Comment: I have replaced it with a real value (#FF181818).

Comment: I think the problem is FrameLayout that makes the views transparent...

Comment: Can you show a screen cap of the problem?  There's nothing `FrameLayout` does by default which would make its children transparent.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you set a background on the TextView?

Comment: @ci_ dunno but it wouldn't solve my problem

Comment: @LarrySchiefer just a sec

Comment: @zatziky it might not solve your problem, but it might give a clue as to what's going on

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I have added a picture

Comment: Maybe the theme <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"> is a problem?

Comment: @ci_ I tried to add a black background to the textView. Bad luck though. Thx for the try anyways.

Comment: Just a random thought: try setting the background on your linearlayout to `@android:color/black` and the background on your scrollview to `@android:color/white` - what do you get then?

Comment: Try switching `error_panel` and the ScrollView.

Comment: @miav I just did due to Aleks G hint. But you are right! Thx >]

Comment: @AleksG I just did what you said and realized the panel should have been stacked like the last one. Big thanks.

Comment: I'm happy for @miav to pick up the points :)

Comment: @Aleks you just don't need them do you :)

Comment: @AleksG good, otherwise it would have been very said. ;)

Comment: @miav I'm not here for the rep - the rep comes secondary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is your ScrollView being transparent. As per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html),

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.

So you need to load the ScrollView first to have it in the background.

Comment: I know this answer has been accepted, but I don't quite understand it. If the ScrollView is on top and has a transparent background, shouldn't the opaque background of the LinearLayout below have been visible through it?

Comment: @ci_ Yes, if it really is opaque. I think the OP just tried to make that background *transparent* (which it already was by default) and never assigned a color to it.

Comment: Ok, no - you are right, it should have. Maybe the OP kept seeing the ScrollView text.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it, maybe the question has some misleading statements in it. Anyway it doesn't matter, he's happy it has been solved, and I got confirmation I'm not going crazy.